# How to get the kendo NumericalTextBox to share the width of a table cell the same way the kendo DropDownList does?

Tags: css, kendo-ui

I have a very simple form laid our in a table with one row and two cells.  I have a kendo NumericalTextBox in one cell and a Text Input in the other.  I have the table width set to 100% and no width on the cells.

The Problem:
The problem is that the NumericalTextBox takes up more that 50% width in it's cell, and squashes up the Text Input.

I have tested this with a kendo DropDownList and it works fine.  It just takes 50%.

Why is the NumericalTextBox pushing out it's cell to more than 50% and how can I stop it doing this?
I realize I can put a style="width:50%" on the table cells, but this is an overhead on larger forms, as if you add a cell you have to go and update all your other cells width percentages etc...
Ideally I just want to be able to say the width of the table is 100% and the cells will equally share that, and each control in each cell will take up 100% of the cell width.

I put together a demo page that shows what is going on:

HTML:

```
<div id="testContainer">
    <strong>Numerical TextBox and DropDownList</strong>
    <table class="mistro-form">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Numerical TextBox:</label>
                <input data-role="numerictextbox"
                data-format="n0"
                data-min="0"
                data-decimals="0" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>Drop Down List:</label>
                <select name="Include Title"
                data-role="dropdownlist"
                data-value-primitive="true">
                    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="No">No</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <table>

    <div style="height:20px"></div>

    <strong>Drop Down List and Text Input</strong>
    <table class="mistro-form">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Drop Down List:</label>
                <select name="Include Title"
                data-role="dropdownlist"
                data-value-primitive="true">
                    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="No">No</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>Include Title:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    <table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
table.mistro-form {
    width:100%;
}
.mistro-form td {
    padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: top !important;
}
.mistro-form .k-dropdown, .mistro-form .k-combobox, .mistro-form  .k-numerictextbox, .mistro-form  .k-textbox, .mistro-form .k-numerictextbox {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    kendo.init($('#testContainer'));
});
```

Here is a fiddle of the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/codeowl/UQdGQ/6/

Thank you for your time,

Regards,

Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I just worked this out.  I just needed to set the table-layout css property to fixed;

eg;

```
table.mistro-form {
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
```

Hope this can save someone else some time ;-)